# Excel Spreadsheet for Work

Tags: excel, function, cell

I would like to make a Function in vba and here is the pseudocode and concept that I need. If anyone can give me help on this you will recieve proper credit for it.

So we have a spreadsheet for the work schedule that has times in each column in row one like such

400 430 500 530 600 etc

These correspond to the time 4:00a, 4:30a, etc. and in Column A we have the names of the Employees, Each half hour that the employee works we fill a 0.5 and if they start on a 45 or 15 we fill it with a 0.25. Is there a way I can have a Function test each cell when the 0.5 start and end, like if the cells to the right and left have nothing in.

Edit: Here is a sample case for Sancho.s

[image: Sample of Finished Product]

Sorry that it is hard to see, the description to the right says "This person has a half and should not be counted as a split shift". The shifts display in Column U are:

1. 5:15-12:30p
2. 6:30-8:30p/10-12p
3. 5:45-9a
4. 5:45-11p

Comment: Can you be more clear? It's hard to tell what you need to accomplish.

Comment: What about just `ISBLANK(A2)`?  No VBA needed?

Comment: But I agree with rwking:  What do you need to accomplish?  A time card capability?  Given a start and end time, you want to figure out how many hours they work?  Or given a schedule, you want to compute hours worked and/or start and end time?  That way we can see if there's an easier way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry its really hard to explain, so I want not the amount of hours they work cause I can do that with SUM, I want when they start and finish. 400 (AM) all the way to 1030 (PM) being the end, they are in a row like this, B1 is 400 C1 is 430 and so on. In column A the Employees names are listed, such as A2 being Bob, A3 being Joe. We fill in 0.5 with the corresponding half hour they work so if Bob works 4:00 am to 6:00 am then we fill in 0.5 for 400, 430, 500, 530. Which means they work 4-6a. I need a function that will test each row and see which cells are filled with 0.5 and create the time.

Comment: "... and create the time" - Do you mean add the total amount of time they worked?

Comment: No like create the time they work, 4-6a, is their shift, thats what I want the end result to be. So if I call the fuction in a cell the result would create the time they worked i.e. 4-6a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas below (with the results they produce) refer to this image. The actions performed by each step (each formula) are possibly self-explanatory.

[image]
[image]

```
Cell $V$4 : =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(($B4:$T4<>0),0),0) -> 3
Cell $W$4 : =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B4:$T4<>"")*(COLUMN($B4:$T4))))-COLUMN($B4)+1 -> 17
Cell $X$4 : =OFFSET($B4,0,V4-1) -> 0.25
Cell $Y$4 : =OFFSET($B4,0,W4-1) -> 0.5
Cell $Z$4 : =OFFSET($B$3,0,V4-1) -> 5:00
Cell $AA$4 : =OFFSET($B$3,0,W4) -> 12:30
Cell $AB$4 : =IF(X4=0.5,TEXT(Z4,IF(MOD(V4,2)=1,"h","h:mm")),TEXT(Z4+TIME(0,15,0),"h:mm")) -> 5:15
Cell $AC$4 : =IF(Y4=0.5,TEXT(AA4,IF(MOD(W4,2)=0,"h","h:mm")),TEXT(AA4-TIME(0,15,0),"h:mm")) -> 12:30
Cell $AD$4 : =W4-V4+1-COUNT($B4:$T4) -> 0
Cell $AE$4 : =AD4>0 -> FALSE
Cell $AF$4 : =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(OFFSET($B4,0,V4-1):OFFSET($B4,0,W4-1)),0),0)+V4-2 -> #N/A
Cell $AG$4 : =AF4+AD4+1 -> #N/A
Cell $AH$4 : =OFFSET($B4,0,AF4-1) -> #N/A
Cell $AI$4 : =OFFSET($B4,0,AG4-1) -> #N/A
Cell $AJ$4 : =OFFSET($B$3,0,AF4) -> #N/A
Cell $AK$4 : =OFFSET($B$3,0,AG4-1) -> #N/A
Cell $AL$4 : =IF(AH4=0.5,TEXT(AJ4,IF(MOD(AF4,2)=0,"h","h:mm")),TEXT(AJ4-TIME(0,15,0),"h:mm")) -> #N/A
Cell $AM$4 : =IF(AI4=0.5,TEXT(AK4,IF(MOD(AG4,2)=1,"h","h:mm")),TEXT(AK4+TIME(0,15,0),"h:mm")) -> #N/A
Cell $AN$4 : =AB4&"-"&IF(AD4>1,AL4&"/"&AM4&"-","")&AC4 -> 5:15-12:30
```

They may work for you.

They give the number of the column (minus one, to avoid counting the column containing names) where data start/end. Formulas do not check the contents of cells having data.

Cell B3 (as an example of row 3) contains `=TIME(INT(B1/100),INT(MOD(B1,100)),0)`, and is formatted as Custom (different from C3). Anyway, row 3 is only for using in formulas, and it can be hidden. Row 1 is just for seeing more clearly the relative column number.

Then you would concatenate with the last formula.

And for adding `a/p` you would only use something like `IF(<time> < TIME(12,0,0), "a","p")` (`<time>` should be replaced by a reference to the cell containing the start/end time that you want -overall or split-). Then, concatenate as indicated above.

You may keep all the cells used here (it's easier for working/debugging),  or create one single formula altogether by combining others. But it will be extremely long (I'm not even sure if it will be longer than some limit from Excel).
My suggestion is that, if possible at all, those cells are kept. You can hide them or, better, group them: select the columns, and Data -> (Outline) Group. You will see a box at the top that lets you collapse/expand the group.

I guess you have everything you need.

Comment: This formula works pretty well the only problem I have left is how am I gonna get the value 2 and 5 to display as "4:30-5a" in another cell

Comment: Also another problem I have is if I put say 0.25 at 430 then it needs to put like 2.5 instead of 2 or something

Comment: @BrentColeman : Expanded answer as per your comment. 2.5 would not be useful, since it is used for offsetting cells (it should be an integer). The way to do it is by interpolation among neighboring cells, using it as the parameter.

Comment: Well then the answer you have provided doesn't help because I need it to differentiate from 0.5 and 0.25 in each cell.

Comment: @BrentColeman : I fixed the formulas, please try them. Notes: 1) Previous formulas did differentiate between 0.5 and 0.25. Moreover, they worked for any fraction (it was beyond your request), as they used interpolation. But they did not work in all cases, and I replaced them with something only useful for 0.5 or 0.25. 2) The case where you have only one 0.25 and all the rest are empty is ambiguous (I guess it will not happen anyway). 3) I guess there cannot be any 0.25 in the middle.

Comment: Yes, the only time there will be 0.25 is the beginning and end. Also there are times where there is a split shift say 1-3 and 5-7 on the same day. Ill post a picture of a sample case.

Comment: @BrentColeman : The formulas provided answer your initial question. They do not allow for interruptions.

Comment: @BrentColeman - Now I posted formulas including split shifts. Please check them out and post feedback.

Comment: Problem I have so far, When I put in your first formula into a cell I get a true false answer not a number. And thank you for helping me this really helps a lot. Also if this isn't to much to ask is there a way for this to be compacted to one cell?

Comment: Also I have a question, I would like to give credit to you when I submit this to my boss for use, would you like me to say you are Sancho.s or another form of naming. If you are not comfortable with saying your name online you can email me at either colembre@uw.edu or brent.coleman@live.com email both if you decide to tell me via email.

Comment: @BrentColeman - 1) Please double check that the layout that you have is exactly the same as that in the image (otherwise the formulas posted would refer to wrong cells). Then you can insert/delete cells as needed.

Comment: @BrentColeman - 3) There's no need to give credit. Your task (rate the answer as you think it best serves the SO community) is already done... (a beer is always welcome).

Comment: If I could give you a beer through the internet I would haha.

Comment: I did exactly the format you have and I am still getting a stupid false in the first column, secondly where am I looking for the end result, cause for the end result of a split shift it needs to be 4:30-5:45a/7:15-8:45a

Comment: @BrentColeman - This is strange, as `MATCH` "returns the position of the matched value within lookup_array, not the value itself... if MATCH is unsuccessful in finding a match, it returns the #N/A error value." Thus, it returns an integer or `#N/A`, not `TRUE`/`FALSE`. You may tinker a little bit, isolating parts of nested functions, to discover the problem.

Comment: So the split is wrong, I don't want the time they aren't working, like what you have 4 to 7, I want what they are working 7 to 10. Also I need it to not say its a split shift it there is only one box without a 0.5, because that means they just have a half and is not on the normal schedule.

Comment: @BrentColeman - For the split: you would ask if there is a split. If so, combine the times <day start>-<split start> and <split end>-<day end>. If not, only <day start>-<day end>. Work always with times; numbers 2,10/4,7 are only intermediates to obtain the final result.

Comment: For the half to not be included I used =(Split Size) > 1 instead of 0 to make sure it doesn't account for a half. I don't think you understand what I am saying, your AB and AC formulas aren't working, they are giving me the time of the split-By this I mean the time the aren't working-I WANT the time they work not the time they don't work.

Comment: @BrentColeman - I have adapted the example (imgs and formulas) to the img you posted. The final formulas give your expected result (except for a/p, you may add that), using `IF(splitsize>1,...` as you said.